# Using attosecond laser pulses to view electrons

Tags: quantum-mechanics, laser, laser-interaction

It is often said in popular media sources that creating shorter and shorter laser pulses will allow us to view electron dynamics as they happen in chemical reactions. This is obviously beneficial in terms of creating new drugs etc.

My question relates specefically to what one would view if we did take an image of an electron during some chemical reaction? I mean would you see some sort of orbital type thing a la every undergraduate textbook on QM or something closer to the images produced by scanning or tunneling electron microscopes?

Comment: Perhaps this helps: http://www.mpq.mpg.de/4857824/10_06_10

Comment: You'd see only moving spot - single electron have been observed with precision ~ Heisenberg uncert.

Comment: See this excellent answer to a newer question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/782972/101743

Answer (score 1):

One of the pitfalls of trying to answer "what would this look like" types of questions is that, in quantum processes, the act of "looking" often necessarily changes the picture.

The problem with your specific question is that it seems to presuppose that the electron is "actually" a small, fast-moving object that if we could only have a quick enough shutter speed on our camera we'd be able to catch an image of - this is simply not how electrons behave, either in chemical bonds or in bound atomic orbitals.

Simply put, no matter how short a laser pulse you use or how quick your shutter speed, there is no 'pinning an electron down,' due to the fact that it is a fundamental law of quantum processes that the more accurately you can determine an object's location, the less certain it's momentum becomes, making it impossible to determine both with 100% accuracy (which is what would be required to take a 'picture' of an electron) - so the answer to whether you'd see something akin to the images produced by electron microscopes is a definite "No."

The orbital picture is a little more tricky - in your specific example where you're firing laser pulses at a bond, you're more likely to excite the electron involved and thus change the orbital it participates in (and thus change the nature of the bond) in the process - this is the issue with trying to measure things without changing them.  If you were to instead try by a different method to passively sense the **charge density distribution** across the atoms participating in the bond, you're likely to produce an image of the charge distribution that does look nearly exactly like the orbital structure predicted by the solution to the Schrödinger equation in 3D space for the bound system you're looking at.

If you then ask how to **interpret** the image you've just produced, then you're likely to get as many answers as you have physicists answering.  You can imagine the electron is smeared out in space corresponding to the picture you've just created.  You can imagine that the electron is a point particle that spends more of its time in the high-density areas of the image you've just created.  You can imagine that the electron is a standing wave that occupies the entire orbital at once.  The fact of the matter is that quantum objects simply don't behave in classical ways, and so trying to imagine what an electron is "like" is going to be frustrating whether you're a physics professor or a layperson, because we've never encountered anything in daily life that it *IS* actually "like."  The good news is you're in good company.