# Attoseconds - generation of pulses of light for study of electron dynamics in matter

Tags: waves, visible-light, electrons, laser, double-slit-experiment

Related to the recent Nobel awarded for the generation of attosecond pulses of light I had a few doubts-

1. In high harmonic generation, why does the intensity of the emitted light drop, then stay constant and then drop again when the frequency of the original beam is increased?
2. While producing attoseconds through a laser beam, why does the peak of one overtone when merging with a trough of another results into destructive interference? (Please don't say it just happens and is a characteristic)

Comment: Is this helpful? [What is an "attosecond pulse", and what can you use it for?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/782972/226902) See also: [2023 physics Nobel prize - why does it matter?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/783000/226902)